# Angular2 HTTP Providers, get a string from JSON for Amcharts

Tags: json, typescript, angular, amcharts, angular2-services

This is a slightly messy questions. Although it appears I'm asking question about amCharts, I really just trying to figure how to extract an array from HTTP request and then turn it into a variable and place it in to 3-party javacript.

It all starts here, [with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759946/angular-2-and-amcharts), which was kindly answered by AmCharts support.

As one can see from the [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YwAy0dOpnS2yPSd6HWth?p=preview). The chart is working. Data for the chart is hard coded:

```
`var chartData = [{date: new Date(2015,2,31,0,0,0,       0),value:372.10,volume:2506100},{date: new Date(2015,3,1,0, 0, 0, 0),value:370.26,volume:2458100},{date: new Date(2015,3,2,0, 0, 0, 0),value:372.25,volume:1875300},{date: new Date(2015,3,6,0, 0, 0, 0),value:377.04,volume:3050700}];`
```

So we know the amCharts part works. Know where the problem is changing hard coded data to a json request so it can be dynamic. I don't think this should be tremendously difficult, but for the life of me I can't seem figure it out.

The first issue is I can't find any documentation on .map, .subscribe, or .observable.

So here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vDxXK2?p=preview) that looks very similar to the first one, however it has an http providers and injectable. It's broken, because I can't figure out how to pull the data from the service an place it into the AmCharts function. I know how pull data from a http provider and display it in template using NgFor, but I don't need it in the template (view). As you can see, I'm successful in transferring the data from the service, with the getTitle() function.

```
    this.chart_data =_dataService.getEntries();
    console.log('Does this work? '+this.chart_data);

    this.title = _dataService.getTitle();
    console.log('This works '+this.title);

    // Transfer the http request to chartData to it can go into Amcharts
    // I think this should be string?
    var chartData = this.chart_data;
```

So the ultimate question is why can't I use a service to get data, turn that data into a variable and place it into a chart. I suspect a few clues might be in options.json as the json might not be formatted correctly? Am I declaring the correct variables? Finally, it might have something to do with observable / map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few things here. First this is a class, keep it that way. By that I mean to move the functions you have inside your constructor out of it and make them methods of your class.

Second, you have this piece of code

```
this.chart_data =_dataService.getEntries().subscribe((data) => {
    this.chart_data = data; 
});
```

What happens inside `subscribe` runs asynchronously therefore `this.chart_data` won't exist out of it. What you're doing here is assigning the object itself, in this case what [`subscribe`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) returns, not the http response. So you can simply put your library initialization inside of the subscribe and that'll work.

```
_dataService.getEntries().subscribe((data) => {

      if (AmCharts.isReady) {
        this.createStockChart(data);
      } else {
        AmCharts.ready(() => this.createStockChart(data));
      }
});
```

Now, finally you have an interesting thing. In your JSON you have your `date` properties contain a string with new Date inside, that's nothing but a string and your library requires (for what I tested) a Date object, so you need to parse it. The problem here is that you can't parse nor stringify by default a Date object. We need to convert that string to a Date object.

Look at this snippet code, I used eval (*PLEASE DON'T DO IT YOURSELF, IS JUST FOR SHOWING PURPOSES!*)

```
let chartData = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < data[0].chart_data.length; i++) {
       chartData.push({
          // FOR SHOWING PURPOSES ONLY, DON'T TRY IT AT HOME
          // This will parse the string to an actual Date object
          date : eval(data[0].chart_data[i].date);
          value : data[0].chart_data[i].value;
          volume : data[0].chart_data[i].volume;
   });
 }
```

Here what I'm doing is reconstructing the array so the values are as required.

For the latter case you'll have to construct your json using `(new Date('YOUR DATE')).toJSON()` and you can parse it to a Date object using `new Date(yourJSON)` (referece [Date.prototype.toJSON() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)). This is something you should resolve in your server side. Assuming you already solved that, your code should look as follows

```
// The date property in your json file should be stringified using new Date(...).toJSON()
date : new Date(data[0].chart_data[i].date);
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/re7yJS?p=preview) with the evil eval. Remember, you have to send the date as a JSON from the server to your client and in your client you have to parse it to a Date.

I hope this helps you a little bit.

Comment: Wow! What a relief! This has been bugging me for quite a while, thanks for the help. I will format the date on the server side so I don't have use the eval function.

Answer (score 0):

If the `getEntries` method of `DataService` returns an observable, you need to subscribe on it to get data:

```
_dataService.getEntries().subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.chart_data = data;
  });
```

Don't forget that data are received asynchronously from an HTTP call. The `http.get` method returns an observable (something "similar" to promise) will receive the data in the future. But when the `getEntries` method returns the data aren't there yet...

The `getTitle` is a synchronous method so you can call it the way you did.

Comment: I updated the plunker with your code, but I can't seem to get it work. So if the data isn't there yet, because it's an observable, what is the best way to do this then?