# How can I parse the information in SimpleChange objects, currentValue property?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the [onChanges lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html) which returns a `SimpleChange` object. Looking inside this object, I see 2 properties: currentValue and previousValue.

I'm passing an array of numbers to this hook, and trying to use `currentValue`, which shows type of Array. Here is a [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Q1iaapfDrsdvbNinkP5) for example. I am console logging out the object to see how to use it.

I tried checking the [docs on SimpleChange](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/SimpleChange-class.html) but there isn't anymore information I can find.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to parse this array? Is it even an Array?
2. Am I incorrectly using this hook? I want to pass data to a custom directive which uses this data to create a chart using ng2-charts. Sort of related to this [other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653045/third-party-js-in-angular2-typescript#34655140) but outside the constructor. The chart should build on data changes passed to the directive instead.
3. Are there alternative objects besides `SimpleChange` that I can use? Any examples from blogs or articles?
4. Any recommended resources to look at about SimpleChange and lifecycle hooks? The docs are a bit dry, and don't have many examples.

Thanks for reading! I'm sorry but I will be heading off for the night, but will check again in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check working - plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DwQ9xF7eIsPfzbNiGloR?p=preview)

Note: You get undefined value because initial value is not set. Look plunker now. By the way, you can take benefit of `Rest Operator` which is **`...`** with `OnChanges` like this,

```
ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) {  // isn't it so simple ?
        console.log('onChange fired');
        console.log('changing', args[0].storage);
        console.log('previous', args[0].storage.previousValue);
        console.log('current', args[0].storage.currentValue);
        console.log('previous value', args[0].storage.previousValue[0]);
        console.log('current value', args[0].storage.currentValue[0]);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I needed to set `storage` to an empty array initially. I guess this trips me up a bit because I feel like I'm expecting `ngOnChanges` to trigger each time I click the button, which should set `storage` to an array of the inputs. I'll definitely be more careful on this type of thing in the future. Thank you for the explanation and examples!